# Using sed to replace partial string by referenceing only beginning of the string

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, text-processing

I have two lines in a file (file.sh):

```
gc=$(sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstat -gc $pid | tail -1 | sed -e 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g')

gccapacity=$(sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstat -gccapacity $pid | tail -1 | sed -e 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g')
```

Using the command line, I want to replace the paths, leaving the remainder in tact. I want to replace the path by using '$JAVA_HOME'bin/jstat

I would like the results to be:

```
gc=$(sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstat -gc $pid | tail -1 | sed -e 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g')

gccapacity=$(sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstat -gccapacity $pid | tail -1 | sed -e 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g')
```

I don't want to add the full path of the original line because I don't know which version will already be installed. I only know that it will start with

```
/usr/lib/jvm/
```

Edit: thanks to @Walter-a

```
**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$** echo $JAVA_HOME  
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle 


**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$** cat test.sh  
gc=$(sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstat -gc $pid | tail -1 | sed -e 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g') 


**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$** sed -r "s#(sudo ).*(/bin/jstat)#\1${JAVA_HOME}\2#" test.sh  
gc=$(sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin/jstat -gc $pid | tail -1 | sed -e 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g')
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Don't forget to show your own attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look what parts you want to match.

```
sed -r "s#(sudo /usr/lib/jvm/).*(/bin/jstat)#\1${JAVA_HOME}\2#" file.sh
```

Comment: Thanks!! Just about perfect!!

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat test.sh 
gc=$(sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstat -gc $pid | tail -1 | sed -e 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g')

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sed -r "s#(sudo ).*(/bin/jstat)#\1${JAVA_HOME}\2#" test.sh
gc=$(sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin/jstat -gc $pid | tail -1 | sed -e 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g')

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` like this:

```
sed "s#/usr/lib/jvm/java[^/]*/#/\"${JAVA_HOME}\"#g" file.sh
```

I'm using `#` as the delimiter for the `s` command because `/` is part of the regular expression.

Comment: thank you @hek2mgl. I've added to the question to clarify.

Comment: I only know that it will start with /usr/lib/jvm/ - so your command wouldn't work for me.